# Is there any way to generate "Lorem ipsum" in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, android-layout

I'm into finding a way to generate `Lorem ipsum` in eclipse when creating views just for dummy texts. for example in Visual studio you can do it simply by typing `lorem` and press tab.
Is there any to do that in eclipse? any Idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't encountered an Eclipse functionality to actually *generate* dummy text, **but** I do highly recommend this workaround (truth be told, I don't think you need different dummy text each time).

Create an Eclipe template. It's an `xml` file that looks like this:

```
<templates>
    <template autoinsert="true" context="java" deleted="false" description="Dummy text" enabled="true" name="Lorem Ipsum">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </template>
</templates>
```

Go to **Java -> Editor -> Templates** and import the above file.

Now, when you write code and type `lore` (which represents the **name** attribute value of the **template** tag above), and hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd>, then it will automatically insert the lorem ipsum text.

**More Tips:**

Add apostrophes to the ipsum text, so that it automatically generates a Java String

Add `+` signs to the ispum text, so that it breaks down the long string when inserted

Set the **autoinsert** attribute to `false`. Then you can see the ipsum description in the proposal

Set the name of the **template** to something like `aaa_LoremIpsum`. Then, in Eclipse, type `aaa` and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd>. That way you can add many templates beginning with `aaa`, and select in Eclipse whichever you like.

I myself have templates for separating methods in a class. (e.g. `aaa_1.StaticFields`, `aaa_2.InstanceFields`, `aaa_3.Constructors` etc.)

Answer (score 22):

In Android Studio, you can preview lorem ipsum TextViews with:

```
tools:text="@tools:sample/lorem/random"
```

You can also use this for Names, Cities, Zip codes, Avatars, and more.

see https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes.html#toolssample_resources

Comment: For a TextView, `tools:src` does not work for me, `tools:text` does though.

Answer (score 4):

They can help.

```
tools:text="@tools:sample/cities"
tools:text="@tools:sample/backgrounds/scenic"
tools:text= "@tools:sample/avatars"
tools:text="@tools:sample/full_names"
tools:text=”@tools:sample/lorem"
tools:text=”@tools:sample/lorem/random"
```

[for other](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes#toolssample_resources)

Comment: I think avatar and scenic should be use with src or background