# Quick debug statement in Java

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, key-bindings, hotkeys

Too often when debugging Android code in Eclipse I find myself typing out:

```
System.out.println("");
```

Is there a way to setup a key binding/ hotkey to paste the above text into a file with the cursor located between the quotes?

Comment: Why not just use the built-in debug stepper in Eclipse? You can see the values of all scoped variables as you step through your code.

Comment: type `sysout` hit `ctrl+enter`

Comment: @AverageGuy because if you want to gather a lot of data for analysis that's actually far slower, especially if you want to sit and think about how values are changing or the order of events.  A debugger is sometimes a useful tool, but it frequently isn't the fastest way to do things.

Comment: Yes, you can define your own shortcuts in Eclipse. This is for generating the infamous "Lorem ipsum" sentence, but you can adapt it to write whatever: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23426493/is-there-any-way-to-generate-lorem-ipsum-in-eclipse

Comment: @Gabe Good point. I find myself using the System.out.println debugging method for stuff like that as well, and I have nothing against it, but if I find myself using it too much, I think to myself: "Shouldn't there be a better way to do this?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Predefined shortcut: Type `sysout`, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

You can customize this by looking at the "Surround with" templates (select the text, right click, surround with, customize).