# Auto generate getter setter for shared prefrences

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sharedpreferences

I know we can generate getter and setters by **Source -> Generate Getter and Setters...**
but my question is is there any way we write our own **Template** for *shared preferences getter and setters* that can generate all the getter setters against all the data members in exactly the same way as Eclipse does for simple Getter and Setters. Its hectic job when you've a lot to save in preferences.
Can eclipse write the following code for me against KEY_SESSTION_TIMEOUT.

```
private static final String KEY_SESSION_TIMEOUT = "sTimeOut";
public static long getSessionTimeOut()
    {
        return sp.getLong(KEY_SESSION_TIMEOUT, 30000);
    }

public static void setSessionTimeOut(long timeOutSec)
    {
        editor.putLong(KEY_SESSION_TIMEOUT, timeOutSec).commit();
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure about Eclipse, but when you use Android Studio, you can create Live Templates. http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/creating-and-editing-live-templates.html

Comment: You can generate templates in Eclipse. Have a look at this post:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23426493/is-there-any-way-to-generate-lorem-ipsum-in-eclipse

Comment: I want my template to be called as many times as the data members in my class.

Answer (score 0):

You maybe looking for [Annotations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/annotations.html) which can help you generate code (getters and setters in your case). Please see how [Project Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter.html) generates getters and setters using annotations.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1918154/1321873 is also a source of some good information on the topic.

Comment: Project Lombok is broken and very unreliable with Gradle builds.